# N-sequential spaces vs Fréchet–Urysohn spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If I'm correct, for an arbitrary topological space $(X, \tau)$ it is known, that $\tau \subseteq \mathrm{SeqOpen}(X, \tau) := \{S \subset X \mid S = \mathrm{SeqInt}(S)\}$ and $\forall S \subset X$ \begin{align*}
[S]_{\mathrm{seq}} \subseteq [S]_{\mathrm{SeqOpen}(X, \tau)} \subseteq [S]_\tau,
\end{align*}
where $[\cdot]_{\sigma}$ means closure w.r.t. the topology $\sigma$, $[S]_{\mathrm{seq}} = \mathrm{SeqCl}(S)$ is the set of all sequentially adherent points of $S$, i.e. $[S]_{\mathrm{seq}} := \{x \in X \mid \exists (x_n) \subset S: x_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{\tau} x\}$ and $\mathrm{SeqInt}(S) := (\mathrm{SeqCl}(S^\complement))^\complement$. Consider the following definitions from the [Wikipedia page about sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space):

- $(X, \tau)$ is called sequential space if every sequentially open subset is open, i.e. $\tau \supseteq \mathrm{SeqOpen}(X, \tau)$. Equivalently, $\tau = \mathrm{SeqOpen}(X, \tau)$. Equivalently, $\forall S \subset X \; [S]_{\mathrm{SeqOpen}(X, \tau)} = [S]_\tau$
- $(X, \tau)$ is called Fréchet–Urysohn space if $\forall S \subset X \; [S]_{\mathrm{seq}} = [S]_\tau$
- $(X, \tau)$ is called T-sequential space if the sequential closure of every subset is sequentially closed, i.e. $\forall S \subset X \; [S]_{\mathrm{seq}} =[S]_{\mathrm{SeqOpen}(X, \tau)}$
- $(X, \tau)$ is called N-sequential space if it is both sequential and T-sequential.

But the space that is both sequential and T-sequential is the space where $\forall S \; [S]_{\mathrm{seq}} = [S]_{\mathrm{SeqOpen}(X, \tau)} = [S]_\tau$, so it is exactly Fréchet–Urysohn, isn't it? Why do we need the N-sequential space notion? Or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I believe you are correct. The 'N-sequential' and 'Frechet-Urysohn' terminologies appear to be synonymous. See the brief discussion on pg. 96 of [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm77/fm7719.pdf) which was linked on wiki.

Comment: @Tyrone  Thank you!